# Is there anything else like TiddlyWiki?

Tags: tiddlywiki

From [Wikipedia - TiddlyWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TiddlyWiki):

> TiddlyWiki is a wiki-modeled
>   client-side single-page application

Does anyone know of anything else like TiddlyWiki? It seems to stand alone in its field.
Specifically, it is a self contained single file that modifies its own content. Besides a web browser nothing else needed to change the page(s) content. It can be accessed via `file:///` without a server and change the content.

Comment: "Anything else" as in a client-side wiki-like system?

Comment: I *think* I've seen a self-contained S5-like presentation tool that could self-edit across disk saves.

Comment: A relevant post is found at http://stackoverflow.com/q/2701039/122139.  Interestingly, I put that up almost precisely three months before yours.  Even more interestingly, TiddlyWiki remains unique!  Okay, except for Wiki on a Stick.  Why the core concept hasn't expanded to realms beyond, I do not know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wiki on a Stick](http://stickwiki.sourceforge.net/) is a similar concept to TiddlyWiki, but laid out slightly different (more traditional Wiki style than the "micro content" approach of TiddlyWiki).  It works well, just a single self-contained, self-modifying HTML file just like TW.

It was last updated in 2012.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few more single-page applications:

- [A flickr collage generator](http://apppad.com/run.jsp?appid=28&view=heroes), written with the [AppPad](http://apppad.com/) framework
- [A sudoku](http://www.thomasweibel.ch/sudoku/) (fails to work in firefox)

They are sometimes known as html applications, but not to be confused with microsoft HPAs (a non-portable alternative).

[Here is a jQuery plugin that handles self-saving.](http://softwareas.com/towards-a-single-page-application-framework)

There are also some [master password bookmarklet generators](http://supergenpass.com/customize/), and some [password generators you can save to disk](https://www.pwdhash.com/), but not the combination of both.

Comment: Something your answer leads to: http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/SinglePageApplications
Would you add it to your answer for completeness?

Comment: @CWH I used that, but had to filter out two thirds that were server based, and only kept Sudoku (also via wikipedia) and the AppPad comment. Better link to individual apps and keep S/N high.

Answer (score 2):

Correct. [Tomboy](http://tomboy.en.softonic.com/mac), [VoodooPad](http://flyingmeat.com/voodoopad/), [Zim](http://zim-wiki.org/), and [Zulupad](http://www.gersic.com/zulupad/) offer desktop wikis, though software must be installed.

Comment: Added self contained note to question. It is about the modification to its single file without other applications.

Comment: added by pimgeek: Zim for Windows has a portable version